# How to send default replay in Hubot Wit

Tags: chatbot, wit.ai, hubot

i have a requirement like sending default messageg to user if confidence is less than 90 .Please help

Answer (score 0):

The hubot-wit.ai code doesn't look very complicated, You probably could just duplicate it in your own `scripts/` dir and tweak the conditional for answer according to your need on https://github.com/tianweiliu/hubot-wit-ai/blob/master/src/wit-ai.coffee#L48